# Data Compression

Tags: compression, backupexec, hp-storageworks

We have an HP StorageWorks 1/8 G2 Autoloader using LTO-6 tapes working with Symantec Backup Exec 15.
I've set the backups which are going to tape to use hardware compresison "if available, otherwise software" compression.
When I look at the Autoloader web console, it says "No" next to the data compression option.
Can I force the software/autoloader to use the full LTO-6 compression rate of 2.5:1?
Currently, the compression ratios I'm getting are around 1.05:1

Comment: You backup what ? BE is not optimal to compress file like a vmdk, or such big file. Big ratio is possible more on fileshare folder with .txt, .doc,etc...

Comment: You can't "force" the compression ratio. It's wholly dependent on the data being backed up.